# View background as the current set background image?

Tags: ios, calayer

I'm developing an app which takes a common background for most of the views displayed on the screen, so let's say I have this background image for my app:

[image]

Now imagine I add a table view and I want my table view section view background to be the app background image specific part it should match in its current position. How do I achieve that effect? I tried setting alpha to 0 but obviously this is what happens when I scroll my table:

*What I want it to look like always:*

[image]

*What happens when I scroll:*

[image]

I also tried setting background image layer's `mask` property but since it only works for one view layer it's not the right thing to do in this case.

I know I'm not explaining myself really well, but I hope you understand at least what I want to do.

Comment: You also need to set the cells background alpha to 0.

Comment: Besides that, the grey separator is still a problem.

Comment: I answered below but please clarify what you are trying to achieve, do you want to see the entire background behind your table view or just on the top where the navigation bar is?

Answer (score 0):

Set your tableView background to be clearColor and do the same for your tableViewCells. Then you must hide the separator lines.

```
 tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

 //in your tableView cellForRowPath method
 cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 cell.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Comment: Do you want to show the whole background on the entire table view or just the top?

Comment: Yeah, I want the whole background to be displayed.

Comment: @DavidRomán I edited my answer to reflect what you wanted to achieve

Comment: I don't actually want the separator to disappear. I want the section view to ignore it when it's behind it.

Comment: So you want the table to basically stop under the navigation bar like old school iOS prior to iOS 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by cutting out the part of the image you need then setting it has the background for the nav bar.

Here is a category to cut out part of the image:

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (Crop)

-(UIImage*)cropFromRect:(CGRect)fromRect;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "UIImage+Crop.h"

@implementation UIImage (Crop)

-(UIImage*)cropFromRect:(CGRect)fromRect
{
    fromRect = CGRectMake(fromRect.origin.x * self.scale,
                          fromRect.origin.y * self.scale,
                          fromRect.size.width * self.scale,
                          fromRect.size.height * self.scale);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, fromRect);
    UIImage* crop = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:self.scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return crop;
}

@end
```

Then in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
//Cut out part of image where nav bar sits
UIImage *navBG = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cVyuX.png"] cropFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44)];

//Set nav bar image
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBG forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

//Remove gray seperator
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

I was able to produce this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I see what you try to achieve but that's not my point really. It's not about the navigation bar. It's about the section view of the table view and every cell it contains.

Comment: @DavidRomán Oh..I think I understand. You want the underlying image to "shine" through to the top section view. Kind of like the parallax thing they are doing on some website now. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yeah, I think you are!